# Jquery best practice, checking for the existence of button/link before attaching an event

Tags: jquery

I have a web page with buttons and links that may or may not exist.
I have jQuery that runs and assigns `click` events to these buttons and links.

Is it bad practice *not* to check for the existence of the buttons or links before I try to attach `click` or any other events? What are the repercussions?

If I should check for the button and link existence, what technique is best practice? 
Checking the length like so - `$('myButton').length != 0` or some other manner?

Comment: jQuery already does this for you, you do not have to check

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's absolutely no need to check in advance unless you need to do something different if it's not there.

Let's assume you may or may not have a button with the `id` value `"myButton"`. If you do this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() { /* ..... */ });
```

...and the button doesn't exist, no handler is hooked up. It's effectively a no-op.

The alternative is to do this:

```
var btn = $("#myButton");
if (btn.length !== 0) {
    btn.click(function() { /* ... */ });
}
```

...which doesn't save you anything (you still have to go looking in the DOM), but does involve more code.

This is one of the great things about jQuery's "set theory" approach: If the set is empty, operations on the set don't *fail*, they just don't do anything.

Comment: `$('.parentThatDoesExist').on('click, 'myButton', function(){})` will handle clicks if your button is added later. It's also more efficient if you have multiple buttons.

Answer (score 2):

There are no repercussions for calling a jQuery function on a jQuery object containing no elements, since jQuery already implicitly handles this for you. It essentially iterates over each of the matched elements acting on them in turn, and attempting to iterate over an initialised, but empty, collection will simply result in no action taking place.

Answer (score 2):

`$('myButton')` is a search through the DOM.  A poorly defined search criteria and an overweight DOM could result in an expensive search operation.

Some devs forget this and execute multiple operations against the same search query such as

```
if ($('myButton').length !== 0) {
    $('myButton').click(...);    
}
```

If `$('mybutton')` returns one or more results, the search above would be run twice.

You could certainly "optimize" this to

```
var myButtonSearchResult = $('myButton');
if (myButtonSearchResult.length !== 0) {
    myButtonSearchResult.click(...);
}
```

However, this can be improved even more by noting that jquery will happily accept operations on an empty set:

```
$('myButton').click(...);
```

jquery is smart enough to run the search, note that it returned and empty set, then ignore the `.click()`.

In short, there is no need to check for the existence of the button first.

Comment: This is arguably not an answer to the question, and irrelevant since you could perform the selection a single time and store the resulting jQuery object in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

No need to check for the existence of the button. 
If "#myButton" does not exist, $('#myButton').click( ... ) won't attach anything, and it's not bad practice.